# File mode flags S_IRUSR, S_IRUSR.... definitions

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, sus

Where can I find the definitions for file mode flags such as  S_IRUSR, S_IRUSR, S_IROTH.. etc...?

I looked on *sys/stat.h* but couldn't find the same?

Comment: If they're not in the file for `<sys/stat.h>`, they're probably in a file included, directly or indirectly, from it.  On a Mac, `S_IRUSR` is defined in what corresponds to `/usr/include/sys/_types/_s_ifmt.h` — that's one of 17 headers included from `/usr/include/sys/stat.h`.  But the details don't matter most of the time, as long as the compiler can find them.  You can search with `grep` or `cscope` or another tool.

Answer (score 0):

On my system they are defined in:

- /usr/include/fcntl.h
- /usr/include/linux/stat.h
- /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/stat.h